# ReactJs : How to extract SVG component text as a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have a SVG component called CircleSVG.

As of now I can get the SVG as a inline component and use directly inside the **div** .

Later on, I want to extract the content of this component and store it as a string.

Something like `const text = JSON.stringify(CircleSvg())` (even though this does not work).

Thanks in advance.

**CircleSvg.js**

```
import React from 'react';
export default () =>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
```

**App.js (Which is working fine)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CircleSvg from './CircleSvg';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CircleSvg/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default (App)
```

**Want to extract the SVG text from the component**

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean exactly by "extract the text from the SVG as a function" ?

Comment: @Tyrannas sorry if I misunderstood. I want to extract the text from the SVG component. How can I do so. Is it by using a function ?

Comment: @Tammy do you mean you want to replace one SVG with another later on (as in, replace the current svg by another)? Or do you mean that you will have some kind of *text* ( as in, a `<text>` tag ) inside your SVG and you want to change that text by calling a function?

Comment: @petajamaja I want to first get the Image text and then later want to process it further for backend processing.

Comment: Let's say you ask for a solution, name it `magicSolution` think of it as a function. So function takes input and return output, like `output = magicSolution(input)`. Now, please clarify what is your input, and what is your expected output.

Comment: @Tammy so if I get this right, you want to get the content of your CircleSvg inline comment as a string ? Something like const text = JSON.stringify(CircleSvg()) ? (not saying this is working, just trying to clarify the need here)

Comment: @Tyrannas yes thanks for getting me correct.

Answer (score 4):

**CircleSvg.js**

```
import React from 'react';
export default ({ onStringify }) => {
    const ref = React.useRef()
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const svgElement = ref.current
        onStringify(svgElement.outerHTML) // this is the "text" you want
    }, [])
    return <svg ref={ref} width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
}
```

**App.js (Which is working fine)**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CircleSvg from './CircleSvg';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CircleSvg onStringify={(svgHTMLText) => { this.saveText(svgHTMLText) }} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default (App)
```

**Want to extract the SVG text from the component**

Comment: I think your answer might use some more explanation of what you're trying to achieve instead of just writing all the solution code

Answer (score 1):

```
const text = JSON.stringify(CircleSVG())
```

This will output in:

`{"type":"svg","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"width":"100","height":"100","children":[{"type":"circle","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"cx":"50","cy":"50","r":"40","stroke":"green","stroke-width":"4","fill":"yellow"},"_owner":null,"_store":{}},"Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG."]},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}`

Which contains the props of the SVG drawing, does it fit your usecase ?

Comment: thank you for your time. I have tested my user case but what I get that I have to get it as it is in SVG file `<svg width="100" height="100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
        Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>`

Comment: any suggestion on this.

Comment: @Tammy rebuilding the html string based on the json object seems pretty straightforward with a map I think, wouldn't that do the trick ?

Comment: Yaa finally i tried with `const text = ""` and parsed it with `DOMParser`.